# Question about English in News title

Tags: tense, headlinese

I know that the English used on a news title sometimes is different than what people usually say. I saw this one today. It says '**xxx passes away**'. So, I am wondering why '**passes**' but not '**passed**'. Thanks.
BTW, is there any books about News title English. Many thanks.

Comment: "News title English" is called _Headlinese_, if that helps. One of the conventions of headlinese is that verbs are often in the present tense.

Comment: Hahahha. Yes, headliness. I didn't even give a thought about that until you say so. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/present-verb-forms-referring-to-the-past) justifies it as trying to make an impression as if the events were happening right now. Personally, I've always seen it as an attempt to imitate the style of referring to historical events, e.g. "In 1492, Christopher Columbus discovers America," but come to think of it, it might actually be the other way round.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks a lot.